# wxPython image problem: Cannot get position from my image using wxpython (but only from the border zone)

Tags: click, wxpython

I've searched some related topics but didn't find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to get the mouse click position from an image displayed in my panel. I can only print position if I click from the white zone outside my image, but cannot print any position if I click on my image. I have attached my code below. Could anyone tell me where I did wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

```
import wx
class MyCanvas(wx.ScrolledWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, id = -1, size = wx.DefaultSize, filepath = None):
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent, id, (0, 0), size=size, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        filepath = r'C:\Users\li58\Documents\work\Code\UAV\UAV-gui\image_000050_LR.png'
        self.image = wx.Image(filepath)
        self.bmp = wx.Bitmap(self.image)
        
        # Create a control that can display the bitmap on the screen.        
        self.image_ctrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self)
        self.image_ctrl.SetBitmap(self.bmp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnClick)

    def OnClick(self, event):
        ctrl_pos = event.GetPosition()
        print("ctrl_pos: " + str(ctrl_pos.x) + ", " + str(ctrl_pos.y))


class ReferenceFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size = wx.DefaultSize, title = "Get position")
        panel = MyCanvas(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = ReferenceFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Simple error, your `Bind` is to the window not the image. Fix it with `self.image_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnClick)`

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, indeed, it solves my problem. Thank you very much!